# is there a way to disable/change kernel console from userspace

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, beagleboneblack

We have Beaglebone Black based custom board with 512MB RAM and 4GB eMMC.
We have kernel console set as /dev/ttyS0 which is debug UART.
After booting in user space, we want to disable(if possible, or switch) console on debug UART.

Is that possible ?

Comment: If you mean the Linux kernel serial console, this is enabled/disabled by the presence or absence of `console` kernel parameters on boot. I am not familiar with the Beagle Bone boot process from eMMC, but somewhere there must be a place to specify kernel parameters. I am not sure what you mean by "booting into user space"; if you mean you want the kernel console active during boot, but disabled afterwards, this is going to be more difficult.

Comment: Kernel parameters are passed from U-Boot. Yes, I was asking same thing i.e. "I want kernel console active during boot and disable afterwards. Yeah. I didn't find how to do it. I thought about one way i.e. create symbolic link to ttyS0 and pass that as kernel command line parameter and after booting delete that symbolic link. But it seems too ugly(am I am afraid of kernel crash/panic), If we can communicate to kernel to disable console that would good.